# explode is not working to split string

Tags: php, file, text

we unable to split the string following code.please Help us.

```
 <?php
$i=0;
$myFile = "testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "no\t";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$stringData = "username \t";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$stringData ="password \t";
fwrite ($fh,$stringData);

$newline ="\r\n";
fwrite ($fh,$newline);
$stringData1 = "1\t";
fwrite($fh, $stringData1);
$stringData1 = "srinivas \t";
fwrite($fh, $stringData1);
$stringData1 ="malayappa \t";
fwrite ($fh,$stringData1);


fclose($fh);



?>
$fh = fopen("testFile.txt", "r");
$
while (!feof($fh)) {
$line = fgets($fh);
echo $line;
}

fclose($fh);
$Beatles = array('pmm','malayappa','sreenivas','PHP');

for($i=0;$i<count($Beatles);$i++)
{
if($i==2)
{

echo $Beatles[$i-1];
echo $Beatles[$i-2];

}
}
$pass_ar=array();
$fh = fopen("testFile.txt", "r");
while (!feof($fh)) {
$line = fgets($fh);
echo $line;
$t1=explode(" ",$line);

print_r($t1);
array_push($pass_ar,t1);
}

fclose($fh);
```

Comment: Fixed your formatting (at least a little). Please create a testcase with a sample string and your explode, this might help us to help you.

Comment: Please specify what exactly doesn't work and what the data looks like you are trying to split.

Comment: what is the output you get with `print_r($t1);` ?

Comment: Please format the code in a proper way, so that anyone can read it. Also please clarify your question, provide e.g. the output/result you want to get and the output/result you currently get.

Answer (score 1):

If i read the code correctly you are writing the string seperated by \t but try to explode with spaces, use:

```
explode("\t", $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [fgetcsv](http://php.net/fgetcsv), since you're just doing a standard tab-delimited input file. Given your sample file of:

```
no [tab] username [tab] password
1  [tab] srinivas [tab] malayappa
```

then

```
$lines = array();
$fh = fopen('testfile.txt', 'rb') or die ("can't open testfile.txt");
while($lines[] = fgetcsv($fh, 0, "\t") { // no line length limit, tab delimiter)
   ...
}
```

will give you

```
$lines = Array(
    0 => Array(
         0 => 'no ',
         1 => 'username ',
         2 => 'password '
    ),
    1 => Array(
         0 => 1,
         1 => 'srinivas ',
         2 => 'malayappa'
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're exploding on whitespace.  Unless there is whitespace in the string your exploding then no, it won't work.

Try using the code markup to make your code a little more readable in order to get better quality responses from people.